# How to do logic expression of date and time format inside dart language?

Tags: flutter, dart, time

usually when using `if` and integer or double number... I am able doing this `if(int x > 6)` (just for example... but how about time? how can I access if (time > 21.00.00).. is there a way to do that

Comment: You could construct two `DateTime` objects with the same date and use [`DateTime.compareTo`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.2/dart-core/DateTime/compareTo.html).

Comment: do you have any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use difference(), to operate comparison with time difference, example:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
final differenceInHours = now.difference(lastUpdate).inHours;
if (differenceInHours >= 2) {
      //some code
}
```

Comment: Am I correct if I define lastUpdate=date and time of yesterday (for example) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can construct two `DateTime` objects with the same date and use [`DateTime.compareTo`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.2/dart-core/DateTime/compareTo.html).  You can make a helper class or helper functions to make this simpler.  For example, something like:

```dart
/// A wrapper around [DateTime] where only the time is relevant and where the
/// date is ignored.
///
/// Note that this ignores time zones.
class Time implements Comparable<Time> {
  Time(int hour, [int minute = 0, int second = 0])
      : _dateTime = DateTime(2000, 1, 1, hour, minute, second);

  final DateTime _dateTime;

  int get hour => _dateTime.hour;
  int get minute => _dateTime.minute;
  int get second => _dateTime.second;

  int compareTo(Time other) => _dateTime.compareTo(other._dateTime);

  bool operator <(Time other) => compareTo(other) < 0;
  bool operator >(Time other) => compareTo(other) > 0;
  bool operator <=(Time other) => compareTo(other) <= 0;
  bool operator >=(Time other) => compareTo(other) >= 0;

  @override
  bool operator ==(dynamic other) =>
      other is Time && _dateTime == other._dateTime;

  @override
  int get hashCode => _dateTime.hashCode;
}

...

if (time > Time(21)) {
  ...
}
```

---

Edit: I suppose we don't really need the `DateTime` if you're willing to do the math:

```dart
/// Note that this ignores time zones.
class Time implements Comparable<Time> {
  Time(int hour, [int minute = 0, int second = 0])
      : _secondsOfDay = ((hour * 60) + minute) * 60 + second;

  final int _secondsOfDay;

  int get hour => _secondsOfDay ~/ (60 * 60);
  int get minute => (_secondsOfDay ~/ 60) % 60;
  int get second => _secondsOfDay % 60;

  int compareTo(Time other) => _secondsOfDay.compareTo(other._secondsOfDay);

  bool operator <(Time other) => _secondsOfDay < other._secondsOfDay;
  bool operator >(Time other) => _secondsOfDay > other._secondsOfDay;
  bool operator <=(Time other) => _secondsOfDay <= other._secondsOfDay;
  bool operator >=(Time other) => _secondsOfDay >= other._secondsOfDay;

  @override
  bool operator ==(dynamic other) =>
      other is Time && _secondsOfDay == other._secondsOfDay;

  @override
  int get hashCode => _secondsOfDay;
}
```